# Can not insert into a table using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The following query was successful when I used in mysql

```
INSERT INTO user(`dev_id`,`email`) VALUES('123','456@gmail.com');
```

But in java jdbc I got this exception:

```
Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.checkForDml(Statement.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1140)
```

My table have 5 columns and 3 columns have default value =null;

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`executeQuery` is only for issuing query statements.  You need to be using `executeUpdate` for an insert, which is for statements (like `INSERT`) that modify data.  Ideally, you should also be using a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `executeQuery()` try to use `execute()` or `executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 1):

Call `executeUpdate()` if u are issuing `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements and not `executeQuery()` which is for executing SELECT statements

Answer (score 1):

You should use [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [executeQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).
JavaDoc:

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an **INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE** statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
>   SQL DDL statement.
>
> Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or
>   CallableStatement.
>
> Parameters:
>       sql - an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.

Also whenever problem arise - check javadoc and try googling first. Stackoverflow is a little bit delicate for your case.